# С++ Дана последовательность из четырех чисел A, B, C, D. Определить формируют ли они убывающую последовательность

Tags: c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<locale.h>
```

Не работает , не знаю почему

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"RU");
    float a, b, c;
    printf("Введите числа ");
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf",&a,&b,&c);
    int d=( a > b && b > c ) ? 1 : 0;
    printf("Результат проверки: %d\n",d );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы забыли про четвертое число под буквой D

Comment: `%lf` - это `double`, `%f` - это `float`, `#include <iostream> ... cin >> a >> b >> c;` - это чтобы не допускать ошибок со спецификаторами в scanf

Answer (score 0):

Потому что спецификатор `%lf` для функции `scanf()` говорит о том, что ответ записывается в `double` (передается адрес на `double`).

Для записи в `float` нужен спецификатор `%f`. А так вы пишете в чужую память. Как раз благодаря тому, что такое возможно, `scanf()` является небезопасной функцией.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string